# Evaluate performance in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, benchmarking

How can i evaluate the performance of a Scheme (R6RS) pieces of code?

I need some procedure like:`(time (oper args))` or `(time oper args)`.

I red the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256647/time-code-in-plt-scheme) but it does not seems to work for me. Do i need to import some module/library?

Thanks.

Comment: You would get more helpful answers if you stated what exact type of Scheme you were using in your question, rather than having us guess.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

`time` Works fine.

```
$ mzscheme
Welcome to Racket v5.2.1.
> (time (/ 1 2))
cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
1/2
>
```

Comment: Hi paul, thank you for your answer. Are you using `#lang racket`?Or are you using standard scheme language?If so, which revision? `R5RS` or `R6RS` ?

Answer (score 2):

Which scheme are you using? `time` seems to be a standard scheme function, so if it doesn't work, you might be using a sub-par implementation or doing something wrong in calling it.

Can you describe what you've tried (pasting appropriate code snippets)?

Comment: I'm using r6rs in DrRacket. If I try to execute: `(time (+ 1 2))` I obtain the error `reference to an identifier before its definition: time`. At the begining i am importing the module `(import (rnrs) (rnrs mutable-pairs (6)))`. Do i need some more library?

Comment: According to the racket docs, it's provided in `racket/base`. I think this means it should be automatically imported, but you may need to use `#lang racket`.

Comment: Yes, i know i can do it in racket, but i need to do it in Scheme R6RS

Answer (score 1):

Can you use another language? this works for me, assuming that you've chosen the option "use the language declared in the source" in DrRacket:

```
#lang racket
(time (+ 1 1))

> cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0
> 2
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. That works for me too, but i'm studying "standard" scheme r6rs, so i can't change language :)

Comment: Why the downvote? OP hadn' specified in the question that he can only use R6RS